# Variable de usuario VBNET. (Ruta variable)

Tags: .net

Quiero acceder a la carpeta de mi usuario, algo como ; C:\Users\felix
Pero sin conocer el usuario "felix" El lenguaje es visual basic. Gracias!

Comment: A parte de la respuesta por parte de AsierR_2, también existe la variable HOME de sistema: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable y aquí ejemplos con varis lenguajes, incluído net: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/77zkk0b6(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Comment: Una alternativa: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/14tx8hby(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si únicamente necesitas sacar el nombre del usuario puedes usar:

```
Environment.UserName
```

Actualización:

```
Dim ruta As String = "C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName
```

Comment: Entonces haria dim username as enviroment.username ? y colocaria en la ruta C:\Users\username ? o como? Quiero copiar un archivo ahi, con el write allbytes

Comment: Creas y asignas el valor a la variable: `Dim username as String = Environment.UserName`. Y dicho String lo unes al otro String para tener la ruta completa. Pon todo el código y te actualizo la respuesta con la correción.

Comment: osea, dim username as string = enviroment y haria File.WriteAllBytes(C:\Users\username\ ?

Comment: `Environment.UserName`, te has dejado UserName

Comment: Muchas gracias. dim username as string = enviroment.username y despues file.writeallbytes(C:\Users\username) ?

Comment: Concatena, necesitas un String `"C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName`

Comment: No funciona, no hay algo como %username% ?en la ruta, asi como cmd

Comment: No te entiendo, añade código por favor.

Comment: Te explico.  File.WriteAllBytes("C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName & "regedit.exe", My.Resources.regedit) Yo quiero que se mueva a una carpeta dentro del usuario, no justo en la carpeta de usuario

Comment: Vale, ya se como File.WriteAllBytes("C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName & "/xdddpapa/regedit.exe", My.Resources.regedit) Muchas gracias!